# How to define multiple CSS attributes in jQuery by using attr()

Tags: jquery

The second part of the attr() instruction -> margin-top fails:

```
var hoeheDrBoxPA = (jQuery(".header-a-p").outerHeight()/2);
var hoeheDrBoxHPA = (jQuery(".text-h-a-p").outerHeight()/2);
var hoeheDrBoxPAML = (jQuery(".header-a-p").css("marginLeft"));
            
jQuery(".et_pb_section_1.header-element").attr('style', 'margin-left:' + hoeheDrBoxPAML + '!important', 'margin-top:' + (hoeheDrBoxPA-hoeheDrBoxHPA) + 'px');
```

The single instructions works:

```
jQuery(".et_pb_section_1.header-element").attr('style', 'margin-left:' + hoeheDrBoxPAML + '!important');
jQuery(".et_pb_section_1.header-element").attr('style', 'margin-top:' + (hoeheDrBoxPA-hoeheDrBoxHPA) + 'px');
```

The first part of the attr() instruction -> margin-left  takes effect

What is wrong here?

Comment: You're overwriting the style attribute the second time.

Comment: Use [.css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

There's no third parameter for `attr()`:

```
jQuery(".et_pb_section_1.header-element").attr('style', 'margin-left:' + hoeheDrBoxPAML + '!important; margin-top:' + (hoeheDrBoxPA-hoeheDrBoxHPA) + 'px');
```

Put it all in the second parameter.

Comment: Yes, of course, perfect!